# How to use d3-cloud in django?

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js

I want to use d3 cloud (https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) in my django project.

but the library source is compiled by Node JS..
so that is like

```js
var dispatch = require("d3-dispatch").dispatch;

module.exports = function() {
  var size = [256, 256],
      text = cloudText,
```

But I can't use Node JS in my django project..how can i use that library in my project?

T_T

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add "https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" to your html imports.

d3.layout.cloud.js will work after that, like in this tutorial :

http://bl.ocks.org/joews/9697914

Comment: Could you also copy the relevant code here for easier reading. As the link may not be valid in future.